# gallery previous and next buttons not working

Tags: jquery, gallery, image-gallery

I have a image gallery made up of two rows of 5 images for a total of 10 images. I will have 20 images and I am trying to have when the user presses the  next button the gallery moves to the next 10 images, previous the user is taken to the previous 10 images. For the life of me I cannot figure out why my previous and next buttons are not working.

jQuery:

```
var $item = $('div.folder'), //Cache your DOM selector
       visible = 5, //Set the number of items that will be visible
       index = 0, //Starting index
       endIndex = ($item.length / visible) - 1; //End index

   $('div#arrowR-spring').click(function () {
       if (index < endIndex) {
           index++;
           $item.animate({
               'left': '-=315px'
           });
       } else {
           index = 0;
           $item.animate({
               'left': '+=' + (315 * endIndex) + 'px'
           });
       }
   });

   $('div#arrowL-spring').click(function () {
       if (index > 0) {
           index--;
           $item.animate({
               'left': '+=315px'
           });
       } else {
           index = endIndex;
           $item.animate({
               'left': '-=' + (315 * endIndex) + 'px'
           });
       }
   });
```

Here is what I currently have: [link to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/YRTzG/16/). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your calculation but you got some errors with the animation. Try to correct it as below:

```
    $('#arrowR').click(function(){
        if(index < endIndex ){
          index++;
          $item.animate({'margin-left':'-=315'});
        } else {
          index = 0;
          $item.animate({'margin-left':'+='+(315*endIndex)});  
        }
    });

    $('#arrowL').click(function(){
        if(index > 0){
          index--;            
          $item.animate({'margin-left':'+=315'});
        } else {
          index = endIndex;
          $item.animate({'margin-left':'-='+(315*endIndex)});
        }
    });
```

Try demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/YRTzG/23/

Comment: namkaha thanks for the response.... how do I set the speed of the animation? Thanks!

Comment: @jsavage980: use $item.animate({'margin-left':'-=315'}, 300);

Answer (score 0):

I can see only 10 items in your HTML code is jsfiddle. But you are trying to change the index of remaining 10 items, which are not present in the HTML. Have a look at HTML code once again and make sure you have 20 items there.

Comment: Thanks for your response PM... will do.